# react-query gef axios instance from react context

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I'm using react-query together with Axios client. I need to create some generic components which are not bound to static Axios instance but they will get instace from React context. So I can share them between multiple projects.

Currently, I have a wrapper around react-query which will provide me Axios instance. Like that:

```js
import { useQuery as useReactQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useAxios } from './axios';

export const useQuery = (queryKey, queryFn, options) => {
  const axios = useAxios();
  return useReactQuery(queryKey, (queryContext) => queryFn(queryContext, axios), options);
};
```

It works but I don't like it. Because I need to import everywhere this wrapper instead of original method and it causes headaches for newcomers on project (I even wrote eslint rule for that).

Does anybody know a better solution? I was unable to find anything better.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a fine solution and also what custom hooks are for. Newcomers should probably adjust to what the current code-base is doing, and if everyone uses your custom `useQuery`, they will also use it. How would they make a correct request without `useAxios` ?

You can also use the existing eslint rule [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) to disallow directly importing `useQuery` from `react-query`.

Lastly, how would you do this differently without `react-query`? You'd likely also have custom hook that calls `useAxios` and spawns a `useEffect` or so. So really, the custom hook is totally fine :)

Comment: I was thinking about some hidden functionality in react-query where you can pass some custom variables into their query context. But I didn't find anything in their codebase. So I will just keep it as is. Thank you for your opinion.